# Is it bad to break out of a labelled block in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

I sometimes write Java code that looks like:

```
success: {
    fail: {
        if (...) break fail;
        // some code
        if (...) break fail;
        // some code
        if (...) break fail;
        // some code
        break success;
    }
    // failure handling code
}
```

Is this bad practice? I could extract this to a method that returns an `Optional<SomeResultClass>`, and then call that method from the main method, but I'm worried that this will be bad for performance.

Comment: Don’t worry about performance until you encounter a problem. You could try profiling it both ways if you are concerned.

Comment: Why do you think it is bad practice? It’s much more readable than your alternative with an extra function added.

Comment: @gnasher729 because it's goto?

Comment: @user353751: One, there is no goto. So that is rubbish. Two, what’s wrong with goto? Can you actually explain that?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is perfectly understandable to `break` out of a loop or switch construct, but I would take care to always break out of *just the innermost* such construct, with an *unlabeled* break.

In your example, you are using a *labeled* break-statement for a case that does not require the use of a label.  You appear to be simply "breaking out of the innermost block."  I see no useful reason why you use either `success` or `fail` here. Therefore, I would advise for the sake of clarity that you do not use a label here.  There is no reason to have either one in this case.

When I see a label in front of a block, I start to get nervous because I know that "there's a hidden `goto` here!"  I'm alerted that at some point the code is going to `goto` this point instead of falling naturally.  And I *really* want this to be "the exception to the rule that is almost never done."